# Inserting CSV data into SQL

Tags: php, upload

I want to insert data from csv file, in to my sql table `excel`, the code is working, but it's not working properly.

**EXAMPLE:**

**Data In Excel file**

kier

kier@Noemail@gmail.com

**output in table excel**

`excel_name`: kier;kier@Noemail@gmail.com

`excel_email`: *blank*

```
 <?php
 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','P@ssw0rd@sql','voters');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if ($_FILES['file']['name']) {
    $filename = explode(".",$_FILES['file']['name']);
    if ($filename[1] == 'csv') {
      $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
      while ($data= fgetcsv($handle)) {
        $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[0]);
        $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[1]);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO excel (excel_name, excel_email) VALUES ('$item1','$item2')";
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
      }
      fclose($handle);

      print "Rois x Dave!";
    }
  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div align="center">
      <p>upload<input type="file" name="file"></p>
      <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="import"></p>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is the excel_name and excel_email is concatenating  in one column which is excel_name, please help me out of this problem. Tyia!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read the document: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

```
array fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\\" ]]]] )
```

modify

```
$data= fgetcsv($handle)
```

to

```
$data = fgetcsv($handle, $length = 0, $delimiter = ';')
```

the delemeter of csv file you uploaded is ; not ,

Comment: thankyou so much! @ryan!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! you saved my life, you're truly grateful! <3

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `$data[0]` contains your information that you need.  I would just use explode again and separate the data before you move it to your DB.

Try changing your while loop to this:

```
while ($data= fgetcsv($handle)) {

  $items = explode(';', $data[0]);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO excel (excel_name, excel_email) VALUES ('$items[0]','$items[1]')";
  mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

}
```

Comment: There's __no__ `,` in `$data[0]`.

Comment: I'm getting old, I didn't see the `;`.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

According to value `kier;kier@Noemail@gmail.com` your delimiter is `;`. Default delimiter for [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#refsect1-function.fgetcsv-parameters) is `,`. So, you should pass `;` as a delimiter argument:

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ';')) {
```

Also, it is always **useful** to debug your variables to see what value they have:

```
var_dump($item1, $item2);
```